# Apache Ignite losing data on node crash?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite 2.4.0, with the official examples with small changes from my side (the code below). I tested the following scenario:

- started 3 instances of https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/ExampleNodeStartup.java (on my local laptop)
- started a client and created a cache with 1 backup

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
  Ignition.setClientMode(true);
  try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
    CacheConfiguration cfg = new CacheConfiguration();
    cfg.setName(CACHE_NAME)
    .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
    .setBackups(1)               
    .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC)
    .setReadFromBackup(true);

    try (IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg)) {
                      putGet(cache);
    }
  }
  }
  ```
- with the client, I use the putGet method to write and read:

  ```
  private static void putGet(IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache) throws IgniteException {
  System.out.println(">>> Cache put-get example started.");

  // Store keys in cache.
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    cache.put(i, Integer.toString(i));

  System.out.println(">>> Stored values in cache.");

  int size = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (cache.get(i) != null)
      size++;
  }
  System.out.println("Cache size:" + size);
  }
  ```

When I first execute the putGet method, of course the output is:

```
>>> Cache put-get example started.
>>> Stored values in cache.
Cache size:100
[01:35:21] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:00.744]
```

Then I stop one node and I execute the putGet method again (this time just the read part). The result is:

```
>>> Cache put-get example started.
>>> Stored values in cache.
Cache size:48
[01:38:25] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:00.406]
```

Shouldn't the cluster be able to recover the data which resided on the crashed node, from the backup on the other two nodes? What is the behaviour of the backup more exactly? Does it need the persistence mode on?

Comment: It seems that if I set the backup to 2, then the data is recovered after one node crashes. Can someone explain why? I understood that with 1 backup per partition, I should have the data split between nodes like this: N1=[A primary ,B backup] , N2=[B primary,C backup] , N3=[A primary, C backup] and like this, it should be able to recover.

Comment: Hi @RemusS, I cannot reproduce the behavior you described. Are you sure that you do not use Ignite native persistence? Is it possible to share log files from all nodes?

Comment: @sk050 - The native persistence wasn't configured. Now I don't have the logs anymore; I'll redo the test and try to share. Did you manage to have the complete data when using 3 Nodes and backups=1 ?

Comment: Yes, I had the complete data. There was no loss of data with that configuration and the test scenario.